# Refreshing parent window once a modal dialog has been closed

Tags: popup, postback

I am using the following code to generate a popup window once a hyperlink has been clicked:

```
currentUserLink.NavigateUrl = "javascript:OpenPopUpPage('/_Layouts/newTest/PopUpEditor.aspx');";
```

Since i wish that the parent window to be refresshed on closing the popup window i used the window.onunload and applied the following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onunload = function () {
        window.opener.location.reload();
    };
</script>
```

yet the following code is not working. What is missing in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code..

```
function ShowModal() {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
        var options = {
            url: 'servername/webpart.aspx',
            tite: 'Add Vendor',
            width: 800,
            height: 475,
            allowMaximize: true,
            showClose: true,
            dialogReturnValueCallback: scallback
        };
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }, 'sp.js');
 }

 function scallback(dialogResult, returnValue) {
      if (dialogResult == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
           SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
      }
```

Source : [SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage from the dialog itself?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44324/sp-ui-modaldialog-refreshpage-from-the-dialog-itself)