# Modal box to create item

Tags: modal-dialog

I'm looking at editng an item in a list then when save is pressed a modal dialog appears which allows adding an item to a second list. When the second list is saved then the modal dialog closes and the orgingal list is also saved.
I've achieved most of this using  PreSaveItem(), when the parent save button is pressed the child list appears in the Modal and when the child list is saved I recieve the alert message confirming child item is saved, clicking ok in the alert returns to the parent item but the parent does not save automatically. Pressing save again brings up the Modal dialog.

It appears the closure of the modal dialog does not return true for the PreSaveitem

```
function PreSaveItem() 
{  

alert("Saving");
return OpenDialog('http://sharesite/sites/mysite1/Lists/Time3/NewForm.aspx');
return true; 
}




//User Defined Function to Open Dialog Framework
 function OpenDialog(strPageURL) 
{
   var dialogOptions = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
   dialogOptions.url = strPageURL;// URL of the Page
   dialogOptions.width = 750; // Width of the Dialog
   dialogOptions.height = 500; // Height of the Dialog
   dialogOptions.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate( null, CloseCallback); // Function to capture dialog closed event
   SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(dialogOptions); // Open the Dialog
   return false;
 }

// Dialog close event capture function
 function CloseCallback(strReturnValue, target) 
{
   if (strReturnValue === SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) // Perform action on Ok.
     {
    alert("Thank you for adding time value");

    }
   if (strReturnValue === SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) // Perform action on Cancel.
    {
    alert( "You clicked cancel!");
    }
 }
```

Comment: My javascript skills are amateur at best, so I apologize for noob questions.  In your `PreSaveItem()` function, you're calling the `OpenDialog()` function with `return OpenDialog(url)`.  `OpenDialog()` returns false, so wouldn't that cause the `PreSaveItem()` function to stop the first list item from saving?

Comment: I used IE Dev tools to follow your functions, and it is indeed returning false (not sure what is causing it, removing the `return false;` in `OpenDialog()` did nothing).

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. I think somehow the code in the braces alert("Thank you for adding time value");
needs to be able to alter the outcome. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm from a C# background, JavaScript is still new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

as iv noted here, you need to understand that there is two things going on here.

1) you have the parent list that your opening up that you edit but havent saved and then you open up a child within the parent form that you also open up and want to creat.

2) saving the child sends a postback from the parent form to save the child details. This loses focus on your parent element.

the child element in JS ModalDialog is essentially an iframe within the parent.

so you have two options.

1) do as i said above by calling as you have but instead have some logic in code to call the return function back to the parent to save.

2) save the parent first using partial postback and then open and save the child

**EDIT**

Ok i have one solution for you.

It means you have to add the new item on the item edit tho before you edit the item it loads the new popup form! i will keep on looking into the main solution. so far i can get the page to load the parent and when you click save it loads the child that you can save but you need to click on save again to clear and save the edited parent!

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(PreSaveAction,"sp.js");

function callthismethod()
{
      var dialogOptions = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
      dialogOptions.url ='http://sharesite/sites/mysite1/Lists/Time3/NewForm.aspx';
      dialogOptions.width = 750;
      dialogOptions.height = 500; 
      dialogOptions.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate( null, CloseCallback); 
      SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(dialogOptions); 
}
```

**EDIT**

You ow me big time ;) , everyone online said its not possible due to multiple partial postbacks going on... but its not ;).

to explain. you have the parent and the parent gets changed... you then click save and that opens the child and you save. It causes a postback but you already have a save item event that is already called causing JS to get confused!

solution....

do the same as above. this time before we call the save item, when we load the parent edit form we want to get the button save event name for later use. we then call the dialog for the child and on save (ok) on the child we can then call the save item event for the parent. the child is saved and closed. On the parent iv put an if statment to tell that we have already done the child so no need to call it but we can go a do a postback using the save button instead! so this is where the button event name comes in handy to call the postback event to save the parent list :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var setTrue = false;
var target;
var contName;

function PreSaveItem()
{   
    //on first load global varible setTrue is false so we can load the popup. 
    //but when true it will save parent list imitating save click event.
    if ("function"==typeof(PreSaveAction)&& setTrue == false)
    {
              //get the clicked save button so that we can use the id (name) later to save when doing a postback.
        target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        contName = target.name;
              //call the save action to load the child list
        PreSaveAction();
    }
    else
    {
         //do postback with parent save button manually
            WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(contName, "", true, "", "", false, true));
    }
}

//function that creates child popup to add new item to a child list
function PreSaveAction() 
{  
      var dialogOptions = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
      dialogOptions.url = 'http://sharesite/sites/mysite1/Lists/Time3/NewForm.aspx'';
      dialogOptions.width = 750;
      dialogOptions.height = 500; 
      dialogOptions.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate( null, CloseCallback); 
      SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(dialogOptions); 
}

//actions (save/cancel) for the child form
function CloseCallback(strReturnValue, target) 
{
    if (strReturnValue === SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) 
    {
       //if we save than set global bool to true
       setTrue = true;
       alert("Thank you for adding time value");
       //call presave item for parent list save
       PreSaveItem();

    }
    if (strReturnValue === SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) 
    {
        setTrue = false;
        alert( "You clicked cancel!");
    }
 }

</script>
```

Comment: Hi
I've tried both your codes. The 1st one with the button works as expected, the button triggers the dialog box.
The second code behaves exactly the same as my original code. When the parent list is edited and save button pressed the dialog appears displaying the child list. Pressing save closes the dialog and a thanks alert appears. However the problem is that the parent list is still open and unsaved. Pressing Save again repeats the cycle! 
Does your example behave the same?

Comment: i am slightly confused? so you have two dialogs... one is the parent and the second is the child... from the parent you could click on a button as an example that would open a child, from the child you can create a new item and click ok to close the child and then close or update the parent?? sorry alot of confusion going on here!

Comment: ahh ok so your looking to edit the parent list, that will inturn open a child dialog that creates an item and then when you close the dialog you want to update the parent?

Comment: yes. is it possible?

Comment: ok i can see that your editing the code for the child but not the parent? how are you calling the child from the parent, is this when your editing the parent list item, i know its on the save button, is it a custom form or out of the box that you listing out for? sorry for the questions, i want to know exactly what you want so i can recreate it on my site to test.

Comment: This is all oob functionality. Using CEWP to add code in the Edit page of parent list. When i add 
function PreSaveItem(){  
alert("Saving");
return true; 
}
The parent list saves as expected. When I add the opendialog function the parent refuses to save but the child dialog opens and child item is created. However the parent does not save, its as the open dialog interferes with the parent.

Comment: it does as your sending a partial postback on the second list, try my update to see if it works :), havent tested it but i think you need to call the open dialog first and then once saved call the return true on the first method to save the parent!

Comment: Hi I've tried your new code. When I go to edit the parent list and press save the parent list saves but no dialog appears. I was expecting the dialog of child list  to appear. I dont think your code works as you have altered the SharePoint function PreSaveItem - this is something sharepoint automatically calls upon saving (its not something I have control over). Am I missing something here?

Comment: There is also a function called  PreSaveAction
http://www.edinkapic.com/2007/10/add-javascript-date-validation-into.html
If it helps.

Comment: Maybe another way around this is to re-direct to newform of child page after saving parent?
http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/sharepoint2010/sharepoint2010customization.aspx?ID=daf8708c-92a1-4ab6-992b-247b5f7b57ed

Comment: iv updated my answer! give me a bit of time and let me recreate what your trying todo on my test machine and ill get back to you witht the solution :)

Comment: just ammended my answer!

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. I didnt expect this to be so problematic. There is something else that is important. I need a relationship between the Parent and Child. The child could have a copy of the Parent ID. Previously, I created a lookup in the child. 
An alternative could be to add two input fields in the parent list edit form. Then use a worflow to create a new item in the child list using the values form the input fields of parent, and copy the ID. A bit of a turnarounf but can this work?

Comment: ok got the solution for you and works as you requested :)

Comment: your main problem is solved now with full working code! for your other issue of getting the id from one list to another should be asked as another question to keep it simple to read as this could get big and confusing for other people to read

Comment: Yes it works !
I'll post the other question on a new thread.
Thanks

Comment: Other thread
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101655/modal-dialog-to-pass-parameter-to-child